# Visual Studio 2010 not start(run) as administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-7-x64, administrator

I have visual studio 2010 installed in Windows-7 OS. It works properly in normal mode or as a normal user but if I run it as administrator then it will show splash screen and after that give error message like "Application cannot start".

I also tried to make it always run as administrator by changing its compatibility property and mark there Run as administrator but in that case also VS not started.

If I turn on UAC and after that try to run VS then it will prompt for permission to run as administrator but then also failed to start.

Is there any solution for this problem?